# GWT Tree traversing

Tags: gwt, tree, traversal

is there an easy way of traversing a gwt Tree? I miss some methods like hasChild()..
I need to image the structur of the gwt tree in this way:

```
            1
           / \
          2   3
             / \
            4   5
```

So it wouldn't be enough to put the TreeItems on a stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TreeItem.getChildCount()` and `TreeItem.getChild(int)`

Tree has `Tree.getItemCount()` and `Tree.getItem(int)`